# SSL em servidor compartilhado

Tags: apache, htaccess, ssl

Tenho um servidor compartilhado com vários sites (todos meus), onde um deles possui certificado SSL.

No entanto, quando digitamos

```
https://outrosite.com.br (com ou sem www)
```

ele exibe o site que está em: (sem redirecionar a URL)

```
https://dominiocomssl.com.br
```

Já tentei fazer a verificação por .htaccess (se não for o domínio com SSL, redirecionar) e por http.conf (quando for requisição na porta 443, redirecionar para a porta 80), mas sem sucesso.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu possa fazer?
Grato.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver? Estou tendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: @rogue_psycho ainda não consegui.

Comment: Isso pode ser problemas no banco de dados, vá em _options e mude a url do seu site

Comment: @rogue_psycho não tem a ver com BD. É configuração do apache.